# How to fix checkmarx scan Reflected XSS specific clients

Tags: asp.net

gets a client-side controlled data for the QueryString_Application element. This element’s value is used in client-side code without being properly sanitized or validated and is eventually integrated into the HTML code

Code

```
if (txtUserPassword.Text == "")
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hiddenPassword.Value))
    {
        txtUserPassword.Text = hiddenPassword.Value;
        txtUserPassword.Attributes.Add("value", hiddenPassword.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: please show some code

Comment: if (txtUserPassword.Text == "")
                                {
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hiddenPassword.Value))
                                    {
                                        txtUserPassword.Text = hiddenPassword.Value;
                                        txtUserPassword.Attributes.Add("value", hiddenPassword.Value);
                                    }
                                    else

Comment: on a different note, is the hiddenPassword a Hidden Field Server Control? if it is, I don't think it's a good idea to store the password in a hidden field

Answer (score 2):

To remediate the Reflected XSS vulnerability, you need to output encode the value before rendering txtUserPassword

```
if (txtUserPassword.Text == "")
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hiddenPassword.Value))
    {
        txtUserPassword.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(hiddenPassword.Value);
        txtUserPassword.Attributes.Add("value", hiddenPassword.Value);
    }
}
```

More prevention techniques can be found on the [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheatsheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html)